# Get the token id from 0x number

Tags: ethers.js, 0x

How can I use ethers.js to get the token id (34797) from this 0x number?

`0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000034797`

I'm not sure which util to use from ethers.js I've looked through the docs and Googled it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [BigNumber](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/bignumber/)

```
hexText = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000034797"
numb = new ethers.utils.BigNumber(hexText).toNumber()
console.log(numb)
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/81udj4a6/6/)

Answer (score 1):

No need for ethers.js, you just need to convert it from hexadecimal to decimal:

```
parseInt('0x34797',16)
```

214935

(which is different than 34797).

Answer (score 0):

```
const { BigNumber } = require('ethers').utils;

const hexString = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000034797";

const bigNumber = BigNumber.fromHexString(hexString);

const tokenId = bigNumber.toString();

console.log(tokenId); // "34797"
```